# Декремент и инкремент в правой части выражения.

Tags: c

```
int a,b,c;
a=10; b=3; c=5;
a=c+b--;
```

Чему будет равно а? Изменит ли своё значение b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b изменит свое значение в любом случае;
а будет равно 5 + 3 = 8;
после всего b будет равно 2;